# How to specify dll onload function for mingw32?

Tags: c, dll, mingw, onload, mingw32

I can compile DLLs properly using mingw and do the exports/imports stuff.  What I am looking for is defining the dll onload function properly as you would in MS VC products.  Google didn't turn up anything.  Anyone have any ideas or a link to a tutorial?

Comment: By "dll onload" you referring to the DllMain? Are you sure it has the right signature? It should be like this: extern "C" DLL_EXPORT BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD Reason, LPVOID LPV). Try adding a code snippet to your question.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean, thanks.

Comment: @aking1012 I didn't say that you should add that DllMain signature to the question but for you to add your own DllMain signature.

Comment: Oh, I don't need it to take any arguments.  I just need to execute function contents with no arguments and no return value on dll load.

Comment: Have you tried compiling this with MinGW? I don't see a reason this shouldn't work.

Comment: @aking1012 You don't need to use the arguments but your function should have this exact signature or it will not work.

Comment: If it's because I was using onLoad instead of DllMain I'm going to feel really retarded...checking thx

Comment: Got it working.  Exact code example below

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, so after some fiddling...it's working.  For anyone else that is having issues here it is.  My issues weren't related to compiling in instead of loading dynamically.  It was a mash-up of a couple of tutorial/question/how-tos that got me to this point.

dll.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "dll.h"

//extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD Reason, LPVOID LPV) {
//This one was only necessary if you were using a C++ compiler

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {

    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            // Code to run when the DLL is loaded
        printf ("Load working...\n");
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            // Code to run when the DLL is freed
        printf ("Unload working...\n");
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            // Code to run when a thread is created during the DLL's lifetime
        printf ("ThreadLoad working...\n");
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            // Code to run when a thread ends normally.
        printf ("ThreadUnload working...\n");
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
} 

EXPORT void hello(void) {
    printf ("Hello\n");
}
```

dll.h

```
#ifndef DLL_H_
#define DLL_H_

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
/* DLL export */
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
/* EXE import */
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

EXPORT void hello(void);

#endif /* DLL_H_ */
```

hello.c

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    /*Typedef the hello function*/
    typedef void (*pfunc)();

    /*Windows handle*/
    HANDLE hdll;

    /*A pointer to a function*/
    pfunc hello;

    /*LoadLibrary*/
    hdll = LoadLibrary("message.dll");

    /*GetProcAddress*/
    hello = (pfunc)GetProcAddress(hdll, "hello");

    /*Call the function*/
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

when compiled with

`gcc -c -DBUILD_DLL dll.c
gcc -shared -o message.dll dll.o -Wl,--out-implib,libmessage.a
gcc -c hello.c
gcc -o hello.exe hello.o message.dll`

produces the expected output of

`Load working...
Hello
Unload working...`

Comment: Thx, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Since mingw is just a windows port of GCC and associated tools, you can use [GCC constructor and destructor attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html). These work for both shared and static libraries, and execute code before and after main is run, respectively. Additionally, you can specify multiple constructor and destructor functions per library.

```
static void __attribute__((constructor))
your_lib_init(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "library init\n");
}

static void __attribute__((destructor))
your_lib_destroy(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "library destroy\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is helpful for the cross-platform stuff if I need to do something similar on the nix side.

Comment: I use previous dll.c,dll.h,hello.c and compile method, just add these functions, and it can not work. I guess because DLL won't call main()

Comment: please be more specific than 'not work'.  DLLs never call main, the dynamic linker loads & executes library constructors, then main(), then destructors.

Comment: I can not see "library init" & "library destroy" in my test.